# Get Wordpress/ACF options on child pages

Tags: php, wordpress, timber

I use Wordpress with Timber (as template renderer), and Advanced Custom Fields. I'm struggling with some sub page options.

My problem is that I can't get the options on the right posts (my jobs) – it's only available on the job overview page.

I've created an options sub page to my custom `post_type` "job", like so:

```
if (function_exists("acf_add_options_page")) {
    acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
        "page_title" => "Job options",
        "menu_title" => "Job options",
        "menu_slug" => "job_options",
        "capability" => "edit_posts",
        "parent_slug" => "edit.php?post_type=job"
    ));
}
```

And I'm able to get that options on the job-overview page, like so:

```
$context["options"] = get_fields("options");
```

But when I run that same command on the posts with `post_type` "job", then it returns `null`.

How can I get that options to affect the posts with `post_type` "job" and not the overview?

---

** **EDIT** **

Okay, so I found out that somehow it had worked, since I could get SOME of the options, and I could edit them in ACF, but I couldn't add new options. Somehow the link to "options" is broken. I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: I don't use Timber, but could it be that "options" is conflicting with the inbuilt options field group in ACF?

Comment: Try to access a specific field of your options: `get_field('field_name', 'option')` where `field_name` corresponds to the field name you have registered.

Comment: get_field('field_name', 'option') doesn't work, on both job overview and on the job. But get_fields("options") work fine on job overview... but not on the job.

Comment: I tried to get_fields("fanjlfasn") to try the idea of conflicting names, but it was the same. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in version 5.3.2. 
This has been fixed in version 5.3.2.1.